# how to seek to the end of file to determine the file size?

Tags: c, filesize, seek

I'm trying to get file size in c programming using seek. I can't use `fseek`, stat.size nor `ftell`, there's a custom operating system UNIX in which I need to run.

How can I find out filesize just by using seek? Is it possible?

```
  FILE *fd = open(argv[1], "r");

  if(fd == NULL)
  {
    printf("Not able to open the file : %s\n", argv[1]);
    return;
  }

  // Set the pointer to the end
  seek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
```

Comment: Why can't you use fseek, stat.size or ftell? Can you use getch()? That is the only way I could think of.

Comment: And what is this `seek` function you're talking about?

Comment: There is a custom made operating system in my operating systems class. It has only specfic functions of open, read, write. No fopen,ftell is present. So its kind of trouble.

Answer (score 7):

`seek`? You mean `lseek` probably. Have a look at the [manual page](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/lseek.2.html). What does `lseek` return?

Answer (score 4):

If you are just wondering whether the construct using `offset = 0` with `whence = SEEK_END` would position the file offset to the end of the file, then "yes" you are right, at least for the "standard `f/lseek()`"s I came across.

`lseek()` should directly return the file offset.
For `fseek()` a following `ftell()` will get you the file offset.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `open()` returns an int, not a `FILE *`.   You have to check for a return value >= 0.  `fopen()` from `<stdio.h>` returns a  `FILE *`.  Also, for the record, `fopen()` and `fseek()` are part of the C standard library.  A UNIX open() is part of POSIX.  So in general, `fopen()` / `fseek()` is more portable.

If you are really on a custom "Unix-like" environment, to where that is no longer true (i.e. you have an custom API instead of  `unistd.h` ) then you're not going to a good answer here without providing more info.  Can you tell us what OS you are really running?

Or like Luther suggested, check the return value of `lseek()` if you are using a normal `<unistd.h>`.